# Linq With Entities List within Distinct List

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL Query that gets Distinct rows of Vendor Contacts, which is returning the proper number of rows:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT v.VendorID, c.ContactID, 
    v.VendorName, 
    c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName,      
FROM VendorContacts vc
INNER JOIN Contact c
    ON c.ContactID = vc.ContactID
INNER JOIN Vendor v
    ON v.VendorID = vc.VendorID
LEFT JOIN [ContactServices] psvc
    ON psvc.ContactID = c.ContactID
    AND psvc.VendorID = v.VendorID
```

I have a method that I want to return of custom type, based on the above query:

```
public List<ProviderContactInfo> GetProviderContactInfo(ProviderContactInfo searchInfo)
{
    using (var db = new MyContext()) 
    {
        var providerContactInfo =
              (from vc in db.VendorContacts
               join ps in db.ContactServices on new { vc.ContactID, vc.VendorID } equals new { ps.ContactID, ps.VendorID } into ps_join
               from ps in ps_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join c in db.Contacts on vc.ContactID equals c.ContactID
               join v in db.Vendors on vc.VendorID equals v.VendorID                                           
               orderby vc.ContactID descending

               select new ProviderContactInfo()
               {
                VendorName = v.VendorName,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                MiddleName = c.MiddleName,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                Services = (from o in db.ContactServices
                            join cps in db.Contacts on o.ContactID equals cps.ContactID
                            join vps in db.Vendors on o.VendorID equals vps.VendorID
                            join s in db.Services on o.ServiceID equals s.ServiceID
                            where ps.ServiceID == o.ServiceID
                            && o.ContactID == c.ContactID
                            && o.VendorID == v.VendorID
                            select s).ToList()
               }).Distinct().ToList();

        return providerContactInfo;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Additional information: The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to
>   the collection ResultType of the specified argument.

Everything works fine when I remove the Services property from the new ProviderContactInfo so I'm sure it's in the way I'm trying to populate that property (which is of type `List<Service>`)

I know there are a lot of questions regarding Linq with Distinct etc but I couldn't find anything on this specific problem.

Please help!

**EDIT This code works:**

```
public List<ProviderContactInfo> GetProviderContactInfo(ProviderContactInfo searchInfo)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext()) 
        {
            var providerContactInfo =
                  (from vc in db.VendorContacts
                   join c in db.Contacts on vc.ContactID equals c.ContactID
                   join v in db.Vendors on vc.VendorID equals v.VendorID                                           
                   orderby vc.ContactID descending

                   select new ProviderContactInfo()
                   {
                    VendorName = v.VendorName,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    MiddleName = c.MiddleName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    Services = (from o in db.ContactServices
                                join cps in db.Contacts on o.ContactID equals cps.ContactID
                                join vps in db.Vendors on o.VendorID equals vps.VendorID
                                join s in db.Services on o.ServiceID equals s.ServiceID
                                where o.ContactID == c.ContactID
                                && o.VendorID == v.VendorID
                                select s).ToList()
                   }).Distinct().ToList();

            return providerContactInfo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you end it with .ToList().Distinct() instead of .Distinct().ToList()?

Comment: Error  CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DAL.ProviderContactInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DAL.ProviderContactInfo>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: have you tried create a custom comparer for ProviderContactInfo and passing it to the distinct function? ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681929/linq-select-distinct-then-order-by-a-different-property/31682037#31682037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add one more step to the process, to avoid applying `Distinct()` on the objects that have a collection (`Services`) property, the LINQ provider does not know how to handle it.

```
var providerContactInfo = from vc in db.VendorContacts
                          join ps in db.ContactServices on new { vc.ContactID, vc.VendorID } equals new { ps.ContactID, ps.VendorID } into ps_join
                          from ps in ps_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join c in db.Contacts on vc.ContactID equals c.ContactID
                          join v in db.Vendors on vc.VendorID equals v.VendorID                                           
                          orderby vc.ContactID descending
                          group ps by new
                          {
                              v.VendorName,
                              c.FirstName,
                              c.MiddleName,
                              c.LastName,
                              c.ContactID,
                              v.VendorID
                          } into g
                          select new ProviderContactInfo()
                          {
                              VendorName = g.Key.VendorName,
                              FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                              MiddleName = g.Key.MiddleName,
                              LastName = g.Key.LastName,
                              Services = (from e in g
                                          from o in db.ContactServices
                                          join cps in db.Contacts on o.ContactID equals cps.ContactID
                                          join vps in db.Vendors on o.VendorID equals vps.VendorID
                                          join s in db.Services on o.ServiceID equals s.ServiceID
                                          where e.ServiceID == o.ServiceID
                                          && o.ContactID == g.Key.ContactID
                                          && o.VendorID == g.Key.VendorID
                                          select s).ToList()
                          }
```

Comment: This is what has appeared to work best so far, at least the Services property is populated and no error has occurred, however my ProviderContactInfo rows are not Distinct as are being returned in the SQL statement from within SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: When I run this code, I'm getting the error CS0103 The name 'ps' does not exist in the current context.  (referring to the line:  where ps.ServiceID == o.ServiceID)

Comment: The join to ContactServices is causing the Contact to appear for as many Services he provides, so instead of getting one contact with 8 services in the services collection, I get 8 of the same Contact with one service each.

Comment: @TrevorBrooks I updated the answer to address this problem.

Comment: We are almost there, I want the return type to be List<ProviderContactInfo>, right now its complaining:  Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<DAL.ProviderContactInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DAL.ProviderContactInfo>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @TrevorBrooks Just call `ToList()` on the `providerContactInfo`. Example: `return providerContactInfo.ToList();`

Comment: I got it working by removing the join to ContactServices, then removing the ServiceID from the where clause in the Services property and boom, it works.  Thank you for your help it caused me to think about the statement differently which led to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be much simplier:

```
public IQueryable<VendorContact> GetProviderContactInfo(ProviderContactInfo searchInfo)
{
  using (var db = new MyContext()) 
  {
    return providerContactInfo=db.VendorContacts
      .Include(vc=>vc.Contacts)
      .Include(vc=>vc.Services)
      .Include(vc=>vc.Vendor)
      .OrderByDescending(vc=>vc.ContactID);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does look much simpler maybe I'm missing something but I get CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type on vc=>vc.Contacts

Comment: You need to `@using System.Linq`

Comment: You need to add `using System.Data.Entity;` for the lambda version of `Include()`

Comment: FYI The error I get is:  Error CS1061 'VendorContact' does not contain a definition for 'Contacts' and no extension method 'Contacts' accepting a first argument of type 'VendorContact' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the navigation property you have set up on VendorContact to reference your Contacts?  Inside VendorContact.cs there should be a property like: `public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }`